# How do I preserve CoreData entries from session to session in Simulator?

Tags: xcode, core-data, ios-simulator

I am building an iOS app in Xcode 9.4 using CoreData to persist data. As I build the app and test it there is a problem with linking to the data from the previous session (after reboots, etc.) because Xcode changes the location where it stores information.

This is important for the short term because it disrupts the workflow, but more importantly in the long term because I want to be able to preload the basic data set when the app goes to the app store.

I would appreciate some solid guidance on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be storing absolute paths to anything.

When the app is installed in the Simulator, if it already exists it is upgraded just like it is on devices. That means your data container may be migrated to a new location on the filesystem. Nothing is deleted between sessions, even if you shut down a specific simulator and start it up again.

Make sure you are using FileManager to search for the documents directory and make all your paths relative to that.